# How to generate a new password for users periodically and notify user of new password?

Tags: php, authentication, drupal, drupal-7, intranet

I am running a private Drupal 7 site where all user accounts are created by admins and managers. I need to ensure that all users have access to the email account that their accounts were created with.

**What is the best way to do the following:**

- Create a user account with an automatically generated password, and
  notify the new user of their password via email.
- After a 4 week period, a new password must be generated for the user
  and set as their active password automatically. The user needs to be
  notified of their newly updated password via email, and the newly
  generated password must be used to access the site until it is reset
  again.

Are there any Drupal 7 modules that can help achieve this?
Any suggestions on building a custom module that can help resolve this?

Comment: I am quite curious about the rationale behind the creation of such a system. To me it sounds like it makes it barely possible for users to consistently memorize their passwords, leading to the infamous "post-it on screen" situation.

Comment: Why not to use force_password_change module?

Comment: do you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Mass Password Reset](https://www.drupal.org/project/mass_pwreset) module, read the module description:

> This module allows users with "Administer users" permission to reset
>   all user accounts and notify all users
>
> Details
>
> The module will reset the passwords of all users except the
>   administrative superuser id 1. You can optionally reset the
>   administrative superuser id 1. Once passwords have been reset, users
>   will optionally receive emails using the Drupal password recovery
>   email. The password recovery email content can be edited at the
>   account settings configuration page.
>
> Use cases
>
> You have a large number of user accounts pre-created and want to send password recovery emails to all users during a site launch.
>       You need to quickly change all passwords on a site for security reasons.

And you can use the [Force Password Change](https://www.drupal.org/project/force_password_change) module too:

> This module allows administrators to force users, by role, individual
>   user, or newly created user, to change their password on their next
>   page load or login, and/or expire their passwords after a period of
>   time.

As [Patrick W](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928106/how-to-generate-a-new-password-for-users-periodically-and-notify-user-of-new-pas/34965232?noredirect=1#comment60784454_34965232) says: You can use the [Generate Password](https://www.drupal.org/project/genpass) module:

> Great utility module which makes the password field optional (or
>   hidden) on the add new user page (admin & registration). If the
>   password field is not set during registration, the system will
>   generate a password. You can optionally display this password at the
>   time it's created.

Reference:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/187633/28275

Comment: The Generate Password module might be a good approach for new users: https://www.drupal.org/project/genpass